# Subscribing to CollectionChanged event with ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, observablecollection

When I create an `ObservableCollection`, how to run additional logic when items added or removed?

```
Public Property Employees As ObservableCollection(Of employee)
    Get
        If _employees Is Nothing Then
            _employees = New ObservableCollection(Of employee)
            AddHandler _employees.CollectionChanged, AddressOf OnEmployeesChanged
        End If
        Return _employees 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of employee))
        _employees = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _employees As ObservableCollection(Of employee)

Protected Sub OnEmployeesChanged()
   'addtional logic...
End Sub
```

When I call

```
Employees.Add
```

or

```
Employees.Remove
```

--> OnEmployeesChanged doesn't get fired and setter won't either.

Employees must notify the collection changed (WPF UI binding to that) but I don't want to use two lines to fire the event

```
_employees.Add
RaisePropertyChanged("Employees")
```

How should the property be structured to handle this?

Comment: your code should work; did you implement the method `OnEmployeesChanged` correctly? I mean the signature of the method should be `Protected Sub OnEmployeesChanged(sender As Object, 
e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know VB, but here it is in c#, i'm sure you can translate it

```
TheList.CollectionChanged += TheList_CollectionChanged;

private void TheList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (string model in e.NewItems)
            {
              //do something when an item is added to the collection
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (string model in e.OldItems)
            {
               //do something when an item is removed here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: make sure to register the CollectionChanged event before you add any items to the collection.