# Update XAML binding on CollectionChanged with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a Xamarin (Android, iOS, WP 8.1 RT) app with MVVM Light. My ViewModel has 2 `ObservableCollections` so my view on WP also contains 2 `ListViews`.

Let's say OC1 is bound to LV1 and OC2 is bound to LV2.

The first OC is never empty.
The second OC is almost always empty.

I'd like to do the following:

- when OC2 is empty: show LV1 and hide LV2
- when OC2 is not empty: hide
  LV1 and show LV2

I tried binding the `Visibility` properties of both `ListViews` to OC2 using a converter that returns `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Visible` depending on the amount of items in the given collection.

That initially works, but the visibility isn't updated when items are added or removed from OC2. It only works when the setter of OC2 is used (which is only at initialization).

This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308781/subscribing-to-collectionchanged-event-with-observablecollection) as I'd prefer to only use XAML-bindings or small modifications to my `ViewModel` with as less code-behind as possible.

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to CollectionChanged event of your OC2 and calling OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OC2)) from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @3615, that fixed it!

In the `ViewModel`:

`OC2.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => RaisePropertyChanged(() => OC2);`